# Android Developers - Controlar que hay noticias nuevas en una sección de la Aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio

querría saber si tenéis alguna idea (no sé como buscarlo por internet) de controlar con un simbolito rojo o cualquier cosa que en mi sección de noticias, hay noticias nuevas desde la ultima vez que abrí la App. Mi sección de noticias se carga de Internet cuando se accede a esa sección del menú (JsonObjectRequest).

Supongo que cuando se inicie la App tendré que de alguna manera traer las noticias y mirar la fecha/hora de la última que haya y tener alguna variable global que se vaya actualizando cada vez que se acceda a la sección de noticias. También he pensado sino algo como tener un estado en cada noticia (leído/no leído) pero al cargarse siempre de internet es más complicado que se guarde ese estado.

En resumen, como cuando tienes en Facebook una notificación en la campanita y hasta que no pinches en ellas no se quita y siempre se pone en rojo cuando hay una nueva (en mi caso se comprobaría solo al arrancar la App).

Gracias!

Comment: Lo más sencillo sería guardar como variable "global" la última fecha de conexión y comprobar si la última noticia cargada (asumiendo que se vayan actualizando por orden cronológico) es de tiempo posterior a la última conexión.

Comment: te refieres a Android Badges : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges te sugiero realizar las preguntas basandote en [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola, no me refiero a los Badges, quizás no me expresé bien. Pero la respuesta de CarlosM. si me ha servido. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: @CarlosM. he realizado lo de variables globales y me va bien salvo que cada vez que ejecuto la aplicación, esa variable está en null.. solo me la guarda si estoy dentro de la misma ejecución. Cuando cierro la app, se limpia y no me serviría

Comment: Al final lo he combinado con SharedPreferences :)